# Method to store C++ lambda: template vs non-template form?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, arguments, c++17

When it comes to receive and store a lambda function, I commonly see this:

```
struct foo {
    std::function<void()> myFunc;

    template<typename F>
    void foo(F&& func) {
        myFunc = std::move(func);
    }
};
```

Does the form above offer any advantage over the form below?

```
struct foo {
    std::function<void()> myFunc;

    void foo(std::function<void()>&& func) {
        myFunc = std::move(func);
    }
};
```

I'm using C++17.

Comment: Just a note: a more directly comparable scenario would be where the second example uses pass-by-value: `void foo(std::function<void()> func) ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first form

```
 template<typename F>
    void foo(F&& func) {
        myFunc = std::move(func);
    }
```

`F&&` is a *forwarding* reference, so your usage of `std::move()` is incorrect - you should use `std::forward<F>(func)` instead. Once you apply the fix, this form will work correctly with both lvalue and rvalue arguments.

In the 2nd form

```
void foo(std::function<void()>&& func) {
        myFunc = std::move(func);
    }
```

`std::function<void()>&& func` is an *rvalue* reference, so you can only call `foo()` with an rvalue, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: So if I *want* to restrict the lambda argument to an rvalue reference, then (2) is correct? Won't it perform any additional allocations?

Comment: I do not see why it should. In both cases, there will be a single allocation to construct std::function.

Comment: So, if I replace `std::move` with `std::forward` in (1), then the only difference will be that (1) accepts both lvalue and rvalue, while (2) restricts to rvalue?

Comment: Another difference in case of rvalue is that in the first case move ctor of functor is invoked, in the 2nd case move ctor of std::function. Not a big difference.